# AWS Error "Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Rate Exceeded" when I use s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-sdk

Some third party application is uploading around 10000 object to my bucket+prefix in a day. My requirement is to fetch all objects which were uploaded to my bucket+prefix in last 24 hours.

There are so many files in my bucket+prefix.

So I assume that when I call

```
response = s3_paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket,Prefix='inside-bucket-level-1/', PaginationConfig={"PageSize": 1000})
```

then may be it makes multiple calls to S3 API and may be that's why it is showing ***Rate Exceeded*** error.

Below is my Python Lambda Function.

```
import json
import boto3
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    from_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    string_from_date = from_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")
    print("Date :", string_from_date)
    s3_paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    list_of_buckets = ['kush-dragon-data']
    bucket_wise_list = {}
    for bucket in list_of_buckets:

        response = s3_paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket,Prefix='inside-bucket-level-1/', PaginationConfig={"PageSize": 1000})

        filtered_iterator = response.search(
            "Contents[?to_string(LastModified)>='\"" + string_from_date + "\"'].Key")

        keylist = []
        for key_data in filtered_iterator:

            if "/" in key_data:
                splitted_array = key_data.split("/")
                if len(splitted_array) > 1:
                    if splitted_array[-1]:
                        keylist.append(splitted_array[-1])
            else:
                keylist.append(key_data)

        bucket_wise_list.update({bucket: keylist})

    print("Total Number Of Object = ", bucket_wise_list)

    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(bucket_wise_list)
    }
```

So when we execute above Lambda Function then it shows below error.

**"Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Rate Exceeded."**

Can anyone help to resolve this error and achieve my requirement ?

Comment: Please try to avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood.

Comment: I sm just upvote your question

Comment: On what line do you get that error? Can you please copy the full stack trace? That message indicates you're trying to invoke the Lamba multiple times (probably more than 1000 times)?

Comment: You should use `botocore.config` to add exponential retry to your throttled API calls. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to your account restrictions, you should add retry with some seconds between retries or increase pagesize

Comment: can you please explain in detail ? and I have already given 1000 page size. I also have to filter  paginate result based on modified data. How I combine all these things together ?

Comment: `botocore` has built in functionality for performing exponential retries on throttling errors. Alternatively, you could write your own paginator using the `nextToken` attribute of non-paginated `lisy_objects_v2` operation and program in a sleep.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to you reaching your quota limit for AWS S3 API calls. The "bigger hammer" solution is to request a quota increase, but if you don't want to do that, there is another way using `botocore.Config` built in retries, for example:

```py
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from boto3 import client
from botocore.config import Config

config = Config(
   retries = {
      'max_attempts': 10,
      'mode': 'standard'
   }
)
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = client('s3', config=config)

###ALL OF YOUR CURRENT PYTHON CODE EXACTLY THE WAY IT IS###
```

This config will use exponentially increasing sleep timer for a maximum number of retries. From the docs:

- Any retry attempt will include an exponential backoff by a base factor of 2 for a maximum backoff time of 20 seconds.

There is also an `adaptive` mode which is still experimental. For more info, see the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html) on `botocore.Config` retries

Another (much less robust IMO) option would be to write your own paginator with a sleep programmed in, though you'd probably just want to use the builtin backoff in 99.99% of cases (even if you do have to write your own paginator). (this code is untested and isn't even asynchronous, so the sleep will be in addition to the wait time for a page response. To make the "sleep time" exactly `sleep_secs`, you'll need to use `concurrent.futures` or `asyncio` (AWS built in paginators mostly use `concurrent.futures`)):

```py
from boto3 import client
from typing import Generator
from time import sleep

def get_pages(bucket:str,prefix:str,page_size:int,sleep_secs:float) -> Generator:
    s3 = client('s3')
    page:dict = client.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket=bucket,
        MaxKeys=page_size,
        Prefix=prefix
    )
    next_token:str = page.get('NextContinuationToken')
    yield page
    while(next_token):
        sleep(sleep_secs)
        page = client.list_objects_v2(
            Bucket=bucket,
            MaxKeys=page_size,
            Prefix=prefix,
            ContinuationToken=next_token
        )
        next_token = page.get('NextContinuationToken')
        yield page
```

Comment: And how I retrieve those objects which was placed in particular "bucket/prefix" in last 24 hours ? Because there are so many files in bucket, and if I use pagination then I have to iterate over all the objects then check condition on modified date which is time consuming. And day by day number of objects will increase so I have to iterate more and more object in future.

Comment: then use the built-in retry funtionality and change literally nothing else in your lambda. I explicitly said not to write your own paginator in 99.9 percent of cases for a reason.

Comment: Not to mention, you are using <iterator>.search which is not really faster than performing the same check in a generator function as I've shown. Both will have to check the iterator elements when they eventually have to collect the items. Generator functions also lazy evaluate.

Comment: The `handle_response_item()` function is called on every iterator element when you do `response.search()`. This is not any more efficient than doing it for each member in a generator function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Again, just to reiterate "and if I use pagination" is really not a valid concern since, in your current code, you **are already using boto3 built-in paginators**, which will iterate through every element of each page when collect it because you call `filtered_iterator = response.search(
            "Contents[?to_string(LastModified)>='\"" + string_from_date + "\"'].Key")`

Comment: Not to mention, that was only my alternative answer, I mainly suggested that you use the functionality built into `botocore` by AWS to address this.

Comment: Downvoting because I provided 2 answer and your only concern was with the answer I said not to use in 99.99% of cases and didn't even apply in that case. Assuming you found your answer (maybe even here) and don't want to pay bounty